# Firebase Authentication verifyPhoneNumber returns null reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get a verification SMS from Firebase Authentication 
When I click on (Verify my phone number) it crashes and returns null reference on the line of verifyPhoneNumber
please help me

I tried to change the phone number 
and I searched very much and cannot solve it

```
private void sendVerificationCode(String phone) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phone,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    }
```

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Unknown
>   Source:2)
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:9)
>           at com.ullb.help.VerifyPhoneActivity.sendVerificationCode(VerifyPhoneActivity.java:67)
>           at com.ullb.help.VerifyPhoneActivity.onCreate(VerifyPhoneActivity.java:39)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)

Comment: Check if the device has google play services and phone authentication is enabled.

Comment: Make sure you have provided number with country code

Comment: Please edit the question to show the exact values of all variables you are passing to `verifyPhoneNumber`.  We should be able to duplicate exactly what you're seeing.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Anyone got answer to this??

Answer (score 0):

If everything with firestore is okay and still not working than the problem may you put the callbacks in wrong position . You should implement callback in on create cycle after the send button is clicked. And this doesn't work if you are using emulator so use real android device one and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Callback**

```
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
        if (code != null) {
            verifyCode(code);
            phoneOtpEdt.setText(code);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage() + "Verification Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        verificationID = s; //Create your own instance variable 
    }
};
```

**Sending OTP to the inputed number (Country code is a must)**

```
private void sendOtpToUser(String number) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            "+91" + number,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
            mCallbacks);
}
```

**Verifying the received OTP**

```
    private void verifyCode(String code) {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationID, code);
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(LogInActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
//                    do something
                } else
                    // do something
            }
        });
```

Don't forget to enable the Phone Sign-in method in Firebase Auth.

I hope it help :)